# strongswan get RANDOM dns

Tags: fedora, vpn, ipsec, strongswan

I'm getting a really strange issue on fresh Fedora 28 MATE with an IKEv2 IPSEC VPN.

First thing: this VPN is currently used by some other clients (some windows and my old Fedora 26) with NO issue.

Configuring it on a fresh installed Fedora 28 i can connect, but, from server, i get "random" DNS servers (random in the real way, the change from a connection to another and are random IP from random classes around the world):

Logs show something like:

```
May  9 14:22:30 localhost NetworkManager[783]: <info>  [1525868550.0975] vpn-connection[0x55f878e58350,067f1bf4-0581-49a7-a18b-542b64fe8b7a,"VPN",0]: Data:   Internal DNS: 144.202.1.204
May  9 14:22:30 localhost NetworkManager[783]: <info>  [1525868550.0975] vpn-connection[0x55f878e58350,067f1bf4-0581-49a7-a18b-542b64fe8b7a,"VPN",0]: Data:   Internal DNS: 80.203.1.204
May  9 14:22:30 localhost NetworkManager[783]: <info>  [1525868550.0975] vpn-connection[0x55f878e58350,067f1bf4-0581-49a7-a18b-542b64fe8b7a,"VPN",0]: Data:   Internal DNS: 112.90.1.204
May  9 14:22:30 localhost NetworkManager[783]: <info>  [1525868550.0975] vpn-connection[0x55f878e58350,067f1bf4-0581-49a7-a18b-542b64fe8b7a,"VPN",0]: Data:   Internal DNS: 16.82.1.204
```

Trying to force on network manager the correct internal DNS everything work fine instead.

I already googled searching for a bug or a known issue but i didn't found anything, someone has/had a similar issue?

Comment: Self-replying... just noticed this bug report: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1574939

Comment: You should put this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a not-pached bug in the strongswan rpm package:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1574939

Fixed in strongswan-5.6.2-6.fc28, issue solved with system upgrade:

```
dnf clean all
dnf update
```